# How does "Power Throttling" technology save energy in Windows?

Tags: windows, intel, cpu-architecture, processor

I know what is the benefits of Power Throttling in windows. But, what is this technology in more detail? Is it the same as DVFS technology? I mean how does the OS save power using the "Power Throttling" method?

Comment: Please see here   https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/99445-how-enable-disable-power-throttling-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Judging from the linked article's picture with a dial ranging from "energy efficent" to "performance", it may simple be a more fine use of the HWP (Hardware P-states) technology. Windows will set a more "energy friendly" settings before scheduling a thread that is marked as background (and not having "foreground" side-effects, like playing music).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Skylake's Hardware P-state management has at least one tuning knob the OS can control, as well as upper/lower bounds on frequency.  Intel calls it "EPP – Energy Performance Preference", as in https://en.wikichip.org/w/images/8/83/Intel_Architecture%2C_Code_Name_Skylake_Deep_Dive-_A_New_Architecture_to_Manage_Power_Performance_and_Energy_Efficiency.pdf#page=11. Linux has `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/energy_performance_preference` per-core settings you can read/write.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html